# Azure , Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation When migration database

Tags: database, azure, tfs, migration, .net-framework-version

Since 05/24/2019 i can't update database when i push code and build on my tfs server.
Previous it work fine have no problem and have no anything change.
I just add this table. It doesn't work...

```
[Table("MyCompany.KeyWordLocation")]
public partial class KeyWordLocation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string keyWord { get; set; }
    public DbGeography location { get; set; }

}
```

And it show error like this.
[image]

At this morning (few hour ago) I found some solution maybe can fix it. By this url below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/exception-with-azure-ad-sync#solution

This moment it gone...  404

Content of that page is

> Problem You run the Azure Active Directory Sync tool Configuration
>   Wizard after you install the Azure Active Directory Sync tool on a
>   Windows Server 2012 Essentials server or a Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Essentials server. In this situation, you receive the following error
>   message:
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
>
> Additionally, an event ID 0 that contains the following description is
>   logged to the Application log in Event Viewer:
>
> Resetting password for SERVERNAME\MSO_
>
> Cause This issue occurs if Office 365 is integrated with a Windows
>   Server 2012 Essentials server or with Windows Server 2012 R2
>   Essentials. In this scenario, a password filter is attached to the
>   Local Security Authentication server (Lsass.exe) that enforces the
>   following domain password policy:
>
> Passwords must contain 8–16 characters. Passwords cannot contain a
>   space or a Microsoft Online Services account name. Because of the
>   password policy restrictions, the Azure Active Directory Sync tool
>   Configuration Wizard cannot reset the password for the
>   MSO_ service account.
>
> Note
>
> The Azure Active Directory Sync tool is not supported in Windows
>   Server Essentials.
>
> Solution Use the Windows Server Essentials Dashboard to manage Office
>   365. We also recommend that you uninstall the Azure Active Directory Sync tool from the server.
>
> If, for any reason, you can't remove the Azure Active Directory Sync
>   tool from the computer, disable Office 365 integration on the Windows
>   Server Essentials Dashboard, and then restart the server. Doing this
>   removes the password policy restrictions.

-I have no " Office 365 " on my server.

-My server is v.2016

I not sure it relate to much with my problem. I can't find anything relate with my issue.
For this moment what is best way should i do?

1. Find new way to publish my code to azure. (maybe move to publish manually and use command in azure to update database...)
2. Find new way to update data base. ( maybe update from local of dev ...)
3. Find from other issue until found some one can fix it...

Or someone can suggest me best thing please tell me